# Split a single column of 5000 addresses in excel to columns

Tags: excel

The addresses are in once column, and the only seperator between addresses is an empty row. I have 5000 addresses and each has approx 4 - 6 fields seperated by rows. The data is pre-formatted from another system.

Anyone know if this can be seperated out into columns per address? I was thinking a macro may do it, but I think the problem is too complex for text-to-columns or any other basic formula.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [**RealCool Import Manager**](http://www.realcoolsoft.com/import-manager-1-0/) to do this. It lets you identify recurring fields in a text file (see [this screenshot](http://www.realcoolsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/main.png)) as fields, then parse the file to extract them into separate Excel columns.